# Hardcore vs Standard Shared Stash Limitations

Tags: diablo-iii

Can you exchange items between your hardcore and standard characters, using your shared stash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It is important to note, however, that Hardcore characters do not share a stash with softcore characters, nor can they trade between each other.  <sup>[[source]](http://www.diablowiki.net/Stash)</sup>

This makes sense since you should not be able to push your HC characters with awesome items you got in SC and also shouldn't have access to HC-specific items on SC characters.

Comment: Just saw it when answering another question... kudos!