# Is it possible to transfer items between my characters in Diablo III?

Tags: diablo-iii

**Background**

I've found a "legendary dagger" for a Witch Doctor in my wizard account.  I was going to try out the Demon Hunter as my second character, but now I'm thinking I can try Witch Doctor instead.

**Question**

Is there a way to transfer the dagger between my characters, without first giving it to a mate, then getting him to give it back to me in a different game?

Also, is there a way to do this between Normal and Hardcore characters?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If all of these characters are on the same Battle.Net account, (ie, you're using a single Diablo 3 CD Key/login) you can do this by putting the dagger in your stash - the stash is shared across all characters on the same account.  The stash is a treasure chest-like object that is usually near the town waypoint in whatever act you are currently in.  It is represented by a "treasure chest" icon on your minimap.

However, hardcore characters cannot access items stashed in your "normal" stash, and vice versa.  That is covered here:

[Hardcore vs Standard Shared Stash Limitations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66288/hardcore-vs-standard-shared-stash-limitations)

There's an intentional wall between hardcore characters and "normal" characters - therefore, there's no way to trade between them.

If they are on different accounts, (ie, you have to log out and log back in with a different account to switch between characters) your best bet is to get both characters into the same game and use the trade interface, or just drop the item on the ground and have the other character pick it up.

Again, since hardcore and "normal" characters can't be in the same game, you can't do this between a hardcore and "normal" character even if they are on different accounts.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. And I'm annoyed I didn't find that hardcore vs standard question when I searched the site - my Googling/searching skills obviously need a tweak... Maybe it's time to turn my [elective mode](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66627/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-to-elective-mode-in-diablo-3) on :)

Comment: @LordScree, the search function on the site is *terrible!* and I myself have posted at least 2 Diablo 3 related dupes, so I wouldn't feel too bad.

Comment: Have to be on the same server as well