# Can I carry over items to another hero?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to transfer items between my characters in Diablo III?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68254/is-it-possible-to-transfer-items-between-my-characters-in-diablo-iii)

Is there a way to carry over weapons, armor, etc... to another hero's game when creating it? I have collected hundreds of items that aren't for my class, and if I were to start a new game with a different hero, is there a way I can get those items over to him/her?

Comment: Sorry I could not find this question on the site, I did not search the right phrase I guess :(

Answer (score 1):

Your stash is shared, as long as your characters are on the same account they can access the same items as long as they are in the stash.